# “to not do” or “not to do”

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, negation, to-infinitive

Specifically with the following sentence, which is more suitable/correct?

> You don't count on humans **to not do** things they're used to doing.
>
> You don't count on humans **not to do** things they're used to doing.

Comment: I'd say the first one, but i'm also one to happily split infinitives just to mildly annoy English teachers. Most of them don't seem to much appreciate it.

Comment: Side comment: "You can't count on..." sounds more natural than "You don't count on..." in this case

Comment: The use of "humans" is odd.  It seems that you are not a human.

Comment: @JamesK that is intentional.

Comment: In logic, it could be argued they do not mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie after saying that, care to explain? that's exactly the essence of the question.

Comment: Ok, let's simplify it: You don't count on x ||to not do y. Versus: You don't count on x not || to do y. This could be written in logical notation: ¬ X  ⇒ ¬ Y versus ¬ X  ¬ ( ⇒ Y).  The double arrow is to or the result. Bear in mind, I only dabble. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Traditional answer

> You don't count on humans **not to do** things they're used to doing.

### Modern answer

Either are okay.

### Reason

One "textbook" (possibly outdated) rule is never to break up an infinitive (or to never break up an infinitive). However, at least in modern American English, this rule is followed or not followed as if there wasn't any such rule at all. In other words, whether to use "not to do" and "to not do" seems to come down to personal preference for many.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays 'to not do' is acceptable in less formal contexts, but 'not to do' is still the first choice in more formal ones.

Google Ngram Viewer shows that, even now, 'not to do' is hundreds of times more common than 'to not do'. The use of 'to not do' is growing, but the use of 'not to do' is growing even faster.

[image: ngram graph]